# Reporting tools for shopping basket price rules useage

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm looking for a way to find information on promotional code in the Shopping basket price rules such as how many times it's been used, on what products etc.

Using a standard google search I've been unable to find anything related to this, so anything to put me in the correct place to find more information would be useful.

To note: I'm looking for a reporting tool and would like to avoid checking each order one by one if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different tables where informations are saved.

- `salesrule_coupon_usage` tells you which rule was used by which customer
- `salesrule` tells you how often a rule was used